# HHVM cannot be installed: "packages have unmet dependencies:"

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, apt-get, hhvm

I am in Ubuntu 14.04, 64bit and am trying to install HHVM. I have already installed Nginx. When I run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 0x5a16e7281be7a449
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://dl.hhvm.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install hhvm
```

I get the following:

```
hhvm : Depends: libgnutls-deb0-28 but it is not installable
       Depends: libmemcached11 but it is not installable
       Depends: librtmp1 but it is not installable
       Depends: libmagickwand-6.q16-2 but it is not installable
```

I've tried running the following:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
```

I've cleared my sources and re-created them. Synaptic Package Manager shows no broken packages... What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by installing Aptitude, to install build-essential:

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
sudo aptitude install build-essentials
```

Then installing some "essentials" i found in a blog post:

```
sudo apt-get install -y unzip vim git-core curl wget python-software-properties
```

Then re-installing nginx:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:nginx/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y nginx
```

Then finally installing HHVM:

```
wget -0 - http://dl.hhvm.com/conf/hhvm.gpg.key | sudo apt-get add -
echo deb http://dl.hhvm.com/ubuntu trusty main | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/hhvm.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y hhvm
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds very much like the wrong apt repository got added. In particular,

```
Depends: librtmp1 but it is not installable
```

The trusty version of HHVM [depends on `librtmp0`](https://github.com/hhvm/packaging/blob/1699f82635ad66f9f208cafdfa14c10693b356b4/hhvm/deb/trusty/DEBIAN/control) (which does exist for trusty).

Did you actually run the commands as indicated above, including the `$(lsb_release -sc)` call? Did you accidentally inject the one for `vivid` first, and `apt` might still be picking that up?

Can you check your apt configuration, to make sure you have the `deb` line for `trusty` and not `vivid`, and there's only the one `apt` line?